# Ending a Twilio Call after a certain time elapses

Tags: web-services, c#-4.0, twilio, twilio-api

I am working on some Twilio based functionality and have a total of 4 sprints to complete.

The first three sprints are over. The code where I connect / forward a call to a user is as follows

```
response.Say(string.Concat("Please wait, transferring your call to  ", strCallServiceUserName));                
response.Dial(strUserDialToPhoneNumber, null, null, null, null, null, strCallerId);
return TwiML(response);
```

Let's just say that I am at my wit's end about completing the last sprint.

Here is what I need to do.

1. I need to make this call duration for 10 minutes.
   (This I think i can handle that by changing the 4th param to number of equivalent seconds)
2. I need to know if there is any mechanism by which I can check when 9 minutes have elapsed in the call. At 9 minutes I just want to interrupt the call with a message...

Questions

1. How do I do this?
2. Do I need to create a conference room and dial into that? Or conversely can this be done without using a conference. Even if I create and use a conference room, the basic question is how to determine that 9 minutes have elapsed in a call duration of 10 minutes,

The big ticket question is how do i find out when the 9 minutes have elapsed?

I have checked out this resource but could not find an answer here
[Modifying live calls](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/voice/modify-live-calls)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

---

Question 1 
Do I have to use conference? The reason i am asking is that I want to limit the participants in that call to two. If I understand correctly, anyone else - a third caller can also dial into the same conference.

As per this resource [modify live calls](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/voice/modify-live-calls) I can fetch the in progress call from

```
/2010-04-01/Accounts/{AccountSid}/Calls/{CallSid}
```

and then make a http post request to terminate the call by providing the parameters url, method & status

So, why does it have to be a conference call? Can't I use the timer to call into an ordinary call started up with the dial verb?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

First up, you can define how long a call is with the [`timeLimit` parameter of the `<Dial>` element](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial#attributes-time-limit). The parameter is set in seconds, so setting it to 600 will get you 10 minute call. You can also use [named parameters](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial?code-sample=code-dial-to-a-phone-number-from-twilio-client&code-language=cs&code-sdk-version=5.x), so you don't need positional parameters.

```
response.Say(string.Concat("Please wait, transferring your call to  ", strCallServiceUserName));     
var dial = new Dial(callerId: strCallerId, timeLimit: 600);
dial.Number(strUserDialToPhoneNumber);
response.Dial(dial);
return TwiML(response);
```

As for speaking a message with 1 minute to go. The best case is actually to dial the callers into a conference and then when the call connects setup a timer to cause a script to dial into the conference as well (the conference will need a phone number assigned) and then when it joins the conference [`<Say>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/say) a message or [`<Play>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/play) an audio file.

Let me know if that helps at all.

---

**Update**

The reason that it needs to be a conference is in order to have the 1 minute warning dial in and tell the callers. You cannot have a third call join a normal `<Dial>` between two numbers because that is a conference call.

You could certainly have some logic on the webhook that connects the conference that ensures that only your two participants and your 1 minute warning are allowed to join this specific conference.

Comment: Phil, thank you so much for your answer. I just want to know a couple of things. I have added these questions to my original question so that the comments are not messed up.

Comment: I have updated my answer to hopefully help out. Let me know if it makes sense.

Comment: Hi Phil, at this point I am stuck. I am new to MVC and the Twilio API. I have updated my question and need some more info.

Comment: Phil, I am extremely sorry. Just having a real bad day. I wanted to add an update of my own and i accidentally erased your update.

Comment: I still see my update, so I don’t understand. I guess the key point is that you need a conference so that a third party, in this case a recorded message can call in and play the message. You can’t dial a third party into a regular phone conversation.

Comment: Hi Phil thanks for your reply. I understand i need a conference. But i don't understand how i am going to do this. Could you give me a broad outline - thanks